# Why does Node sometimes hang when allocating Int8Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typed-arrays

Consider the following two programs:

```
// works.js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16777216);
var HEAP8 = new Int8Array(buffer);
```

and

```
// fails.js
var HEAP8;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16777216);
HEAP8 = new Int8Array(buffer);
```

Run `node` then enter `.load works.js`. Everything seems happy. Now exit `node`.

Run `node` again and enter `.load fails.js`.

On my machine loading `fails.js` interactively leads the `node` process to consume over 1GB of RAM and 100% CPU, and the final statement blocks the interpreter forever. `works.js` just runs and returns as expected.

Is there some good reason for the difference? Or should I be writing a bug report?

Curiously enough, running either script directly from the command line works fine:

```
node works.js    # exits normally
node fails.js    # exits normally
```

**UPDATE**: I'm using node 0.12.0 on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Got the same result on OSX with iojs v2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some good reason for the difference? Or should I be writing a bug report?

I doubt there is a good reason for this, you should [file a bug](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues).